# My regex code is not working on website's server, but working properly on my local server

Tags: regex

My code:

```js
$("[name='ism']").keyup(function() {
    $(".ism-xatolik").text("");
    $("[name='ism']").css("box-shadow", "none");

    var ism;
    ism = $("[name='ism']").val();

    ism = ism.trim();

    var ismTek = ism.match(/[^A-Za-z]/g);

    if (ismTek && ism !== "") {
        $(".ism-xatolik").text("Iltimos, faqat harflardan foydalaning*");
        $("[name='ism']").css("box-shadow", "0 0 5px red");
    } else {
        $(".ism-xatolik").text("");
        $("[name='ism']").css("box-shadow", "0 0 5px green");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='ism'>
<div class='ism-xatolik'></div>
```

I need to validate firstname. It is validating in my localhost, but when I entered a capital letter in my live website, it thinks capital letters can not be included.

I am using PHP laravel framework on my project.

Please, go to this link to see my page: https://uzgeniusa.uz/narxlar
Just click the button on price list, then input capital letter, you have an error. Then, please look at the page source code, everything is ok there

Comment: Your question is not clear... what is the current behaviour and what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: @SimonCorcos current behavior is it matches capital letters. Desired behavior is not to match them. Seems pretty clear to me. What isn't clear is *why* it isn't working. Provide some code so we can see what the issue is.

Comment: Instead of using regex to identify characters that you don't want, I'd suggest verifying that the input is a string of letters by using `/^[a-z]+$/i.test(ism)`

Comment: @jmcgriz I just tried, but it did not work

Comment: @Gary It is working here, but It is working partially on my server. For example, when I type capital letter, it outputs an error message

Comment: I am using Laravel. Perhaps, there is a problem on my server. Does anybody have  an idea about what it is not working properly on my server?